# Why would "don't" be used with a proper noun that can be replaced with "he"?

Tags: grammar, verbs

There's a song called "Where The Devil Don't Go" by Elle King and I'm confused with its title and [lyrics](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/elleking/wherethedevildontgo.html):

> Cast me down where the devil don't go
>
> Devil don't go where I make my home

I expected "where the devil doesn't go" but there's "don't". I could explain to myself that the second line is an addressing to the devil himself but what's with the first?

My modest theories are:

1. It's a kind of religious form like "God bless you".
2. I missed an important part of my education and now I'm not able to understand that simple things.

Comment: The simple thing that you may be missing here is that in song lyrics, as in poetry (sacred and profane) the meter (beats per line) is more important than grammar. "Don't go" is two syllables (stressed then unstressed) and fits the music. "Doesn't go" is three syllables (stressed, unstressed, unstressed) and doesn't fit.

Comment: @user105719: You are right, and at the same time, incomplete. It must be noted that there is a huge amount of poems / songs which use proper grammar, regardless of any other restrictions: rhyme, meter...

Answer (score 1):

> I expected "where the devil doesn't go" but there's "don't"

This isn't so much breaking grammatical rules, as using a non-standard dialect.  That's why you didn't learn it; you are learning the dialect that newspapers and professional papers are written in, that is less regional.

Comment: Yep, it would be ungrammatical in standard English, but it’s not supposed to be standard English. It *is* grammatical in the non-standard variety the songwriter is using.

Answer (score -3):

> I expected "where the devil doesn't go" but there's "don't".

You are totally right, the song does not respect the English grammar.

Good and very good poem / lyrics writers succeed to write poems / lyrics with good grammar, as you already have noticed.

However, the less successful ones use their right to use improper grammar, hiding behind reasons as "rhyme" and "meter" and "beat" and what-not.

Please continue using correct English (which you proved you already know), and forgive the people who cannot do it.

Comment: Songwriters and poets are completely free to ignore formal rules of grammar, if they do, there is no implication whatsoever of low quality.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I agree with the first part, although they usually choose to not break the rules of grammar (eventually they bend it in extreme cases). I have trouble understanding the last part: "there is no implication whatsoever if low quality" - I do not understand _what_ you want to say.

Comment: I think Michael is saying (and I agree) that if a songwriter deliberately uses non-standard language in their songs, that does not make the songs worse. In fact, your answer is insulting.